# SwifUI iOS 14 Picker Binding

Tags: swiftui, picker, ios14

SwiftUI Pickers appear not to work in iOS 14 as they used to.
The lower one works perfectly, while the first one produces this error:

*"displayModeButtonItem is internally managed and not exposed for DoubleColumn style. Returning an empty, disconnected UIBarButtonItem to fulfill the non-null contract."*

Is there anything I am missing? I don't know how to get the upper version to work again?

It does work if I change the picker style to the Wheel, however I prefer to use the "DefaultPickerStyle", where it works like a Navigationlink revealing the list of options in a second page.

```
struct WeekdayPickerViewNEW1 : View{
    
    @Binding var selection: Int
    var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: self.$selection, label: Text(self.text)){
            Text("1").tag(1)
            Text("2").tag(2)
            Text("3").tag(3)
        }
    }
}
struct WeekdayPickerViewNEW2 : View{
    
    @State var test: Int = 0
    var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: self.$test, label: Text(self.text)){
            Text("A").tag(1)
            Text("B").tag(2)
            Text("C").tag(3)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry, kind of forgot to ask the question. My bad. Just edited the post accordingly.

Comment: You may try to set the style of your NavigationView to `StackNavigationStyle()`.

Comment: Unfortunately adding 
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
does not work in this case.

Comment: Do you mean `WeekdayPickerViewNEW1`? How do you use it? It work fine here, Xcode 12 / iOS 14. I tested it in `NavigationView/Form` (hoping you meant that by *where it works like a Navigationlink revealing the list of options in a second page*)

Comment: So after quite a lot of trial and error it turns out you are absolutely right, it does work. However I was trying to save/load the Value of the @State using the .onAppear / .onDisappear Methods of the parent View. Seems like SwiftUI doesn't like that. Is there any workaround for this problem?